# What are the determinants of tumor metastasis

Tags: cancer

Under what conditions do tumors migrate? Is it due to hostile microenvironment conditions, drug application, mutations, or other causes? Are there any migration probability values (I am doing an in silico research) or equations to determine this?

Comment: There are a lot of mathematical approaches to understanding metastasis.  [Review articles](https://concept.journals.villanova.edu/article/download/1708/1588) might be a good place to start.  The long and short of the biology of metastasis is *it depends.*  Tumors are highly variable, some metastasize easily and in particular ways, others do not.  It is a heavily studied area of medicine.  I will add that it is probably not a "hostile microenvironment" that encourages metastasis; it is probably better to think of the proximate causes rather than such ultimate causes.

Comment: You might also want to read about the [epithelial-mesenchymal transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithelial%E2%80%93mesenchymal_transition) as an initiator of metastasis.

Comment: So here's a sort of review article that may help you https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/maini/PKM%20publications/367.pdf .. and perhaps this one as well http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4626809/